# Sorting algorithm best case/worst case scenario

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is a practice exam question i'm working on, i have a general idea of what the answer is but would like some clarification.

The
following
is
a
sorting
algorithm
for
n
integers
in
an
array.
In
step
1,
you
iterate
through
the
array,
and
compare
each
pair
of
adjacent
integers
and
swap
each
pair
if
they
are
in
the
wrong
order.
In
step
2,
you
repeat
step
1
as
many
times
as
necessary
until
there
is
an
iteration
where
no
swaps
are
made
(in
which
case
the
list
is
sorted
and
you
can
stop).

What
is
the
worst case
complexity
of
this algorithm?

What is the best case complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Share your general idea of what the answer is.

Comment: This question is not a practical programming problem (You do not have a program that isn't working.) This is a theoretical problem. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RaymondChen Not so sure about that, we have lots of these questions on [algorithm] (questions about "software algorithms" are on-topic). Since it's already here I would leave it, but vote to close it for a different reason (lack of research effort). Maybe OP gets around to editing the question for the better though

Comment: Isn't it a Bubble sort what you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the algorithm presented here is a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

The worst case complexity here is O(n^2).

The best case complexity is O(n).

Here is the explanation:

The best case situation here would be "Already sorted array". so all you need is N comparisions(To be precise its n-1) so the complexity is O(n).

The worst case situation is reverse ordered array.

To better understand why its O(n^2), consider just first element of reverse ordered array which indeed is a largest element, to make this array sorted you need to get that element to the last index of the array. Through the algorithm explained in the question, on each iteration it takes the largest element one index towards its actual position(last index here) and it requires O(n) comparisions to move one posistion. and hence O(n^2) comparision to move it to its actual position.

Comment: Indeed it is. Maybe add a link?

Comment: @NiklasB. I added a link for Vishwanath's answer

Comment: Could you provide an explanation? I'm really trying to deepen my understanding.

Comment: @NiklasB. an explanation would be even better than a link.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, but at the very least a link to Wikipedia helps the cause. I think OP can go from there on his/her own... It's not going to become dead any time soon

Comment: You have asserted a reversed array is the worst case. Have you proven it?

Comment: @Nemo References are  on Wikipedia. No use in restating the proof here if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

In the best case, no swapping will be required and a single pass of the array would suffice. So the complexity is `O(n)`.

In the worst case, the elements of the array could be in the reverse order. So the first iteration requires `(n-1)` swaps, the next one `(n-2)` and do on...
So it would lead to `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is bubble sort.  But if you are measuring complexity in terms of comparisons, you can easily be more precise than big-O.

In the best case, you need only compare n-1 pairs to verify they're all in the right order.

In the worst case, the first element is the one that should be in the last position, so n-1 passes will be needed, each advancing that element one more position toward the end of the list.  Each pass requires n-1 comparisons.  In all, then, (n-1)^2 comparisons are needed.